# Stacked bar with labels at the right end using ggrepel and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I need a bar chart that shows different segments of a dataframe, including years, revenue sources, and revenue figures for a company. I can generate the chart, but there are issues with the labels. They are disorganized, not properly aligned with their respective segments, and don't have the same color as the corresponding segment.

I have tried using base R, but specially I have used `ggrepel` and the `geom_text_repel` function with ggplot2. The function seems to work but shows the wrong result.

```
type_vec <- c(rep("ecommerce",4),rep("third_party",4),rep("retail",4),rep("services",4),
              rep("marketplace",4))
year_vec <- rep(c("2010","2011","2013","2014"),5)
revenue_vec <- c(8709, 8773, 8974, 9876, 1772, 1891, 1915, 2872, 5727, 5820, 5904, 6500,
  1, 2, 3, 6, 4370, 4463, 4479, 4817)


data_raw <- tibble(year=year_vec,type=type_vec,revenue=revenue_vec)

data_df <- data_raw %>% 
  mutate(group = as.factor(if_else(revenue < 11, "other", type ))) %>% 
  mutate(group = fct_relevel(group, "other", after=Inf),
         label_type = if_else(year == 2014,type, NA_character_))

theme_stacked_bar <- function( ) {
  
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.margin = unit(c(2,7,2,2),"cm"),
    axis.text = element_text(size=3)
  )
}
  
data_plot <- ggplot(
  data_df %>% filter(group != "other"), 
  aes(year, revenue, group = type)
) + 

  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    data = data_df %>% filter(group == "other"),
    fill = "grey85",
    alpha = .5) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    aes(fill = group)) +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  theme_stacked_bar()
data_plot


data_plot <- data_plot +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(color = group, label = label_type ),
    # family = "Lato",
    # fontface = "bold",
    size = 8,
    direction = "y",
    xlim = c(2014.8, NA),
    hjust = 0,
    segment.size = .7,
    segment.alpha = .5,
    segment.linetype = "dotted",
    box.padding = .4,
    segment.curvature = -0.1,
    segment.ncp = 3,
    segment.angle = 20
  ) +

    coord_cartesian(
    clip = "off",
       ylim = c(0,25000)
      )

    data_plot
```

Expected

I want the labels aligned with the right segments , also i want the words to match the color palette used

[image: stacked bar chart]

Result

I got the stacked bar chart with the labels messy and wrong colors. I am unable to organize the labels and also I am unable to add the color of the color palette used in the bars.

[image: stacked bar chart]

Comment: You may want to have a look at the position functions from [package 'ggpp'](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpp/) and two web pages with examples of [their use together with 'ggrepel'](https://www.r4photobiology.info/galleries/nudge-and-repel.html) and on [labeling bar charts, including stacked ones](https://www.r4photobiology.info/galleries/bar-col-plots.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this?

[image: demo]

(I changed the colour palette as the lighter blue shades aren't really readable as text labels; feel free to change based on your needs.)

Code with comments inline to explain the modifications made to your original version:

```
ggplot(
  data_df %>% filter(group != "other"), 
  aes(year, revenue, group = type)
) + 
  # removed the first geom layer as it's not really contributing anything
  geom_col(                                           # geom_col() = geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    aes(fill = group)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"), # add this so the fill palette appiles
                                                      # to both colour & aesthetic mappings
                    palette = "Dark2") +              # I changed to a darker palette for readability
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(color = group, label = label_type ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),           # specify stacked position to follow bar layer's default position
    size = 8,
    direction = "y",
    xlim = c(2014.8, NA),
    hjust = 0,
    segment.size = .7,
    segment.alpha = .5,
    segment.linetype = "dotted",
    box.padding = .4,
    segment.curvature = -0.1,
    segment.ncp = 3,
    segment.angle = 20
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(
    clip = "off",
    ylim = c(0,25000)
  ) +
  theme_stacked_bar()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Excellent I tried it in my real datasets and it works. I have an additional question though , if you could help me. my real plot has a title using element_textbox() from geom_text(), I use it because I can use the whole area of the plot to display the title and accepts markdown also wraps the title, I am using it with a different solution creating a dataframe with midpoints of the last bar and adding a year. The title and an additional logo at the right bottom are displayed correctly,

Comment: the only issue with my approach is that sometimes the labels are misplaced 
and the color of the labels get mixed up. So your solution is the best but creates another issue. Now my title extends only to the plot area , it does not reach the area above the labels outside the plot. Any suggestions I can try ? I would appreaciate it dearly.

Comment: @EdwinAcuña I suggest that you pose another question on this, with these details + sample data so that others can diagnose it more easily. It can be quite challenging to iterate this sort of issue over comments. A new question will have greater reach, so others may answer it first :) else I can take a stab at it next time I log into SO.

Comment: great thanks , I tried  some code and fixed the issue , everything is perfect. thank you!!